# Angular bootstrap typeahead: Use ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to use ng-repeat in case of  Angular bootstrap typeahead instead of "for loop" for iterating over the items?

```
  <span>
     <input type="text" style="overflow:auto" ng-model="selected" 
         typeahead="item for item in filterInput($viewValue)">                                                                     
  </span>
```

Comment: ng-repeat inside input will duplicate the input itself and not the typeahead dropdown. Any reason you want to do this ?

Comment: Instead of the for loop I want to use ng-repeat for my typeahead. I want to run a directive or fire some function when the loop ends. Is that possible?

Comment: you mean when the dropdown finishes loading ? what exactly do you want to do inside that function ? There might be a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes when the dropdown finishes rendering. Is there any way to fire a function/event/directive?